# Transfer files from one directory to another if they match a condition using python

Tags: python, unix

I need to use python to move/copy files from one directory to another in UNIX if the filenames match a certain condition, eg filename1 = extra_filename2.
I have prepared the below script but its giving errors.
Can somebody correct me please:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import shutil, fnmatch, os

for filename in os.listdir('/home/root/Desktop/'):
        try:
                file1 = fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.txt')
                file2 = fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.txt')

        if file1 = extra_'file2'
                print "True"

shutil.copy2('/home/root/Desktop/file1','/home/root/Desktop/Archive',follow_symlinks=True)
```

Comment: there is so much wrong with this ....

Comment: "Giving errors" - That's not helpful. What errors? What is the stack trace? What is happening vs what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @Andy I bet a bunch of them are about that `if` line -- this snippet won't even compile.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I count multiple things on that line too. `=` vs `==`, an undefined `extra_` variable, no `:` at the end of the statement, concatenation without an operator. Did I miss any on that line?

Answer (score 3):

```
import shutil,glob
for fname in glob.glob("/path/to/some*.txt"):
    shutil.copy("/dest/path",fname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your response, my apologies that i couldnt convey my query and i just provided a raw code, it was absolutely wrong.
Basically i was looking for something like below :

#

import os
import shutil
import re

source = ("sourcePath")

files = os.listdir(source)

for name in files:
        fullpath = source + "/" + name
        Name2 = name + "filename2"
        #print fullpath
        if re.match("filename regex", name) and Name2 in files:

```
            #shutil.rmtree("destinationPath"+name)
            shutil.copytree(fullpath, "destinationpath"+name)
            shutil.copytree(fullpath, "destinationpath"+Name2)
```

print "Finished"

#